# Java : space makes a difference in compilation?

Tags: java, string

I was making a program (A Piglatin sort of...), in which I unintentionally missed a variable in the statement:

```
String a = "R"++'a';
```

It should actually have been `String a = "R"+text+'a';`. The compiler produced an error. But, when I made it:

```
String a = "R"+ +'a';
```

The program compiled.

I am wondering why putting a space made the difference even though Java does not care whether you put a space or not in certain statements, like : `String a="ABCD";` is the same as `String a  =   "ABCD";`

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Can you please post the error message from the compiler?

Comment: Yup. The compiler says **';' expected.** and puts the error pointer on the same statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`++` is an *operator* in its own right (pre or post increment).

Putting it between a string and a char literal is not syntactically valid.

But with `"R"+ +'a'`, the second `+` will bind to the char literal `a` and will act as the unary plus operator (this operator has a very high precedence). This is **not** a no-op: in Java it has the effect of *promoting* the *type* of `a` to an `int`. This type promotion means that the output will be `R97` rather than `Ra` (97 is the ASCII number for `a`). The remaining `+` acts as the string concatenator.

Answer (score 2):

Because `++` is a unary operator, while `+ +` is interpret as following:

1. `"R"+` represents a string concatenation and then the second argument (for the concatenation is evaluated)
2. `+'a'` represents an explicit setting of sign (`+`) to the (numeric) `char` literal `'a'`. Because you've explicitly set the sign of the value, it is treated as a numeric one and hence the result of `+'a'` is the numeric representation of the character `'a'` and that's why the result is `R97`.

The same way if you did `String a = "R"+ -'a';` then the numeric value of `'a'` (which is `97`) would be negated and the result would be `R-97`.

If you, however, had just ignored the `+` sign before `'a`', then `'a'` would have been treated as character, not as numeric, and the result would be `Ra`.

Answer (score 2):

`String a = "R"++'a';` implies `"R"++` and `'a'`. The `'a'` is not appended by a + operator, and hence the error has to be there.
On the other hand, String a = `"R"+ +'a';` means `"R"` then a `+` operator, and then a `+'a'`(i.e 97). Hence it compiles. The output will be **R97**

Answer (score 0):

Operator ++ is applied to numbers and increase this value by 1.
When You write + + 'c' it means You want to add string and positive char